# Filter InfluxDB SQL by Windows LogicalDisk

Tags: sql, windows, influxdb

I'm trying to understand how to get a Chronograf dashboard setup so that I can show specific Windows disks (SQL Server). Given a basic query of the entire disk system:

```
SELECT mean("Percent_Free_Space") AS "mean_Percent_Free_Space" FROM "flajacksdb"."autogen"."win_disk" WHERE time > :dashboardTime: AND "host"='wafflehousesqlserver' GROUP BY time(:interval:) FILL(null)
```

I would think I could do something like this to filter for the Z drive:

```
SELECT mean("Percent_Free_Space") AS "mean_Percent_Free_Space" FROM "flajacksdb"."autogen"."win_disk"."Instances"."Z" WHERE time > :dashboardTime: AND "host"='wafflehousesqlserver' GROUP BY time(:interval:) FILL(null)
```

But this does not return data. Does anyone know how to figure out to filter for the lower objects?

Comment: Why the SQL tag? This is not SQL related.

Comment: Can you show the data you currently store in the database? 'show series'

Comment: I can show data.. for instance:  win_diskio,dc=oregan,host=serverrobo1,instance=2\ S:,objectname=PhysicalDisk

Comment: This is the query I'm looking for: SELECT mean("Percent_Free_Space") AS "mean_Percent_Free_Space" FROM "oregan"."autogen"."win_disk" WHERE time > :dashboardTime: AND "host"=catmix' AND "instance"='E:' GROUP BY time(:interval:) FILL(null)